# How to remove dynamically added collapsible in JQM

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I am building a UI with the reference of Jquery Mobile but stuck in a idea how to remove a dynamically added collapsible in the example given in Jquery Mobile Demos.

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/collapsible-dynamic/

I have generated an example for the same. [JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/koxodipona/edit?html,output)

**JS Used:**

```
console.log("DOM Load");
$( document ).on( "pagecreate", function() {
    var nextId = 1;
    $("#add").click(function() {
    nextId++;
      var content = "";
    content += "<div data-role='collapsible' id='set" + nextId + "'>";
    content += "<h3>Section " + nextId + "</h3>";
    content += "<p>I am the collapsible content in a set so this feels like an accordion. I am hidden by default because I have the 'collapsed' state; you need to expand the header to see me.</p>";
    content += "<button id='removeStyle" + nextId + "' class='removeStyleBtn ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-mini'>Remove</button></div>";

    $( "#set" ).append( content ).collapsibleset( "refresh" );
    //$("#set" + nextId+ " :button").button().button('refresh');
    $("#set" + nextId).collapsible( "expand" );
    console.log("collapsible set " + nextId + " added !!!");
  });
  console.log("pagecreate triggered !!!");

  $(".removeStyleBtn").click(function() {
    console.log("Removed Element !!!!!");
  });

});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id` need to be unique per element so remove button `id`(not needed in your case)

And then do:-

```
$(document).on("click",".removeStyleBtn",function() {
    $(this).closest('div[data-role="collapsible"]').remove();
});
```

Put this code outside of `$(document).ready(){..});`

Output:- https://jsbin.com/vuyehocate/edit?html,js

Comment: Thanks the answer was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Mobile is enhancing the markup in Your page, but You don't even need to know exactly the enhanced DOM-Tree hierarchy. In the provided demo, what You need is to search for the first `collapsible` above the `Remove` button.

Here is it:

```
$(document).on("vclick", ".removeStyleBtn", function() {
  var parentCollapsible = $(this).closest('div[data-role="collapsible"]');
  var parentCollapsibleSet = $(parentCollapsible).closest('div[data-role="collapsibleset"]');
  $(parentCollapsible).collapsible("destroy");
  $(parentCollapsible).remove();
  $(parentCollapsibleSet).collapsibleset("refresh");
});
```

BTW, I would suggest You also to filter the `pagecreate` event just only for the page which contains the collapsible-set (or use a `switch` statement) otherwise - if You have more than one page - the code will be executed more than once. In Your example, something like this:

Markup:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page-with-collapsible">
```

JS:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page-with-collapsible", function() {
  var nextId = 1;
  $("#add").click(function() {
    nextId++;
    var content = "";
    content += "<div data-role='collapsible' id='set" + nextId + "'>";
    content += "<h3>Section " + nextId + "</h3>";
    content += "<p>I am the collapsible content in a set so this feels like an accordion. I am hidden by default because I have the 'collapsed' state; you need to expand the header to see me.</p>";
    content += "<button id='removeStyle" + nextId + "' class='removeStyleBtn ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-mini'>Remove</button></div>";
    $("#set").append(content).collapsibleset("refresh");
    $("#set" + nextId).collapsible("expand");
    console.log("collapsible set " + nextId + " added !!!");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <link href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/git/jquery.mobile-git.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/git/jquery.mobile-git.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log("DOM Load");
        $(document).on("pagecreate", function () {
            var nextId = 1;
            $("#add").click(function () {
                nextId++;
                var content = "";
                content += "<div data-role='collapsible' id='set" + nextId + "'>";
                content += "<h3>Section " + nextId + "</h3>";
                content += "<p>I am the collapsible content in a set so this feels like an accordion. I am hidden by default because I have the 'collapsed' state; you need to expand the header to see me.</p>";
                content += "<button id='removeStyle" + nextId + "' class='removeStyleBtn ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-mini'>Remove</button></div>";

                $("#set").append(content).collapsibleset("refresh");
                //$("#set" + nextId+ " :button").button().button('refresh');
                $("#set" + nextId).collapsible("expand");
                console.log("collapsible set " + nextId + " added !!!");
            });
            console.log("pagecreate triggered !!!");


            $("#delete").click(function () {
                if (divx != null) {
                    var element = document.getElementById(divx);
                    element.remove();
                    divx = null;
                }
                
            });

        });

        $(document).on("click", ".removeStyleBtn", function () {
            var parentDiv = $(this).closest('div[data-role="collapsibleset"]')[0].childElementCount;
            if (parentDiv > 1) {
                $(this).closest('div[data-role="collapsible"]').remove();
            } else {
                alert("sorry ,this is the last page!");
            }
            
        });

        var divx;

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("div:jqmData(role='collapsibleset')").each(function () {
                bindEventTouch($(this));
            });

            function bindEventTouch(element) {
                element.bind("tap mousedown", function (event, ui) {
                    divx = $(event.target).closest('div[data-role="collapsible"]').attr('id');
                    var count = element.childElementCount;
                    if (element.hasClass('ui-collapsible-collapsed')) {
                        //alert(element.attr('id') + ' is closed');
                    } else {
                        //alert(element.attr('id') + ' is open');
                    }
                });
            }

        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
  
  <div data-role="page" class="jqm-demos">


    <div role="main" class="ui-content jqm-content">
  
        <div data-demo-html="true" data-demo-js="true">
            <button type="button" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="right" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" id="add">Add</button>

            <button type="button" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="right" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" id="delete">delete</button>

            <div data-role="collapsibleset" data-content-theme="a" data-iconpos="right" id="set">
                <div data-role="collapsible" id="set1" data-collapsed="false">
                    <h3>Section 1</h3>
                    <p>I'm the collapsible content.</p>
                    <button id="removeStyle1" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-theme="b" class="removeStyleBtn">Remove</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        </div>

        </div>

</body>
</html>
```